# Python: Wrong output in sum of digits of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got wrong output when I run the programme.I use python 3.4.3 version.Below is my program code,

**CODE:-**

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

def sumOfDigits(n):
    summ=0;
    while(n!=0):
        r = n%10;
        summ+=r;
        n/=10;
    return summ;


input_num = raw_input("Enter a number : ");
n = int(input_num);

print("sum of digits of the number %s is %d" % (input_num,sumOfDigits(n)));
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
Enter a number : 54928
sum of digits of the number 54928 is 31
```

Comment: You are using Python3. Use `//=` instead of `/=`.

Comment: `sum(int(value) for value in input_num)`

Comment: Thanks @Amadan...it is running properly.

Comment: @Amadan, you should make that an answer so OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
def sumOfDigits(n):
r = 0
while n:
    r, n = r + n % 10, n / 10
return r


input_num = raw_input("Enter a number : ");
n = int(input_num);

print("sum of digits of the number %s is %d" % (input_num,sumOfDigits(n)));
```

Worked for me perfectly.